# Calculate point, given x, y, angle, and distance

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Excuse my ignorance and use of incorrect terms, but...

I have x and y coordinates, and the angle that the entity is facing on a 2D plane.  I want to find the correct point, say 5 units in front of the point I have.

Examples:

```
If my entity is at 0, 0 and is facing east (0 degrees), my point would be 5, 0.

If my entity is at 0, 0 and is facing north (90 degrees), my point would be 0, 5.

If my entity is at 0, 0 and is facing north-east (45 degrees), my point would be ???.
```

I can't even figure it out in my head, let alone figure out the formula I need.  I assume I need trigonometry, but I'm old and haven't used it since 1997.

Comment: $x=5\cos\theta$, $y=5\sin\theta$. $\theta$ is the angle between the line of sight from the entity to the point and the positive $x$ axis.

Comment: @DavidMitra Again, my ignorance, what am I doing wrong?  I'm my browser's console to test it... 0 works `5*Math.cos(0)`= 5, `5*.Math.sin(0)`=0, but 90 does not `5*Math.cos(90)` = -2.2403680806458506, `5*Math.sin(90)` = 4.4699833180027895... I tried converting degrees to radians but that didn't help either.

Comment: When you converted to radians, what did you get? You should have obtained $90^\circ$ is $\pi/2$ radians.

Comment: I did, I think I'm now having issues with not understand how JavaScript handles floats... `90 * Math.PI / 180` does give me `1.5707963267948966`, as does `Math.PI / 2`, but when I say `Math.cos(Math.PI / 2)`, I get 6.123233995736766e-17, which may very well be close to 1, but I don't know how to cast that into a usable integer now. =[

Comment: Yes, the "e-17" and the end means "times $10^{-17}$, which in effect shifts the decimal point to the left 17 times, introducing zeroes (so it's $.0000000000000000612...$). $\cos(\pi/2)$ is exactly $0$.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In general, if $\theta$ is the angle between the line of sight from the entity to the point and the positive $x$ axis, then
$$
x=5\cos\theta,\quad\text{and}\quad y=5\sin\theta. 
$$
Here $\cos$ is the cosine function and $\sin$ is the sine function.

When calculating values of these, it is important to realize that the angle can be measured in various ways, the most common being degrees and radians.   $360$ degrees is $2\pi$ radians. In general to convert $x$ degrees to radians, multiply $x$ by $\pi/180$.

You can use either measurement system for the angle, but when calculating $\sin$ and $\cos$ using a device, make sure you measure the angle as needed by that device.

In your example, with an angle of $45$ degrees, if you  find $\sin(45^\circ)$ and $\cos(45^\circ)$ from a calculator, make sure the calculator is set to use degrees as the measure. Using Google's calculator (which by default uses radians), we must input $\sin(45\ \text{ degrees})$ and $\cos(45\ \text{ degrees})$. This returns

$$\sin(45^\circ)\approx.707\quad\text{and}\quad\cos(45^\circ)\approx.707.$$  Your point would then have $x$ coordinate

$\ \ \ \ \ x\approx5\cdot (0.707)=3.535$

and $y$-coordinate

$\ \ \ \ \ y\approx5\cdot( 0.707)=3.535$.

In radians, $45$ degrees is $45\cdot{\pi\over 180}={\pi\over 4}$ radians; and you could  compute $\cos(\pi/4)$ and $\sin(\pi/4)$  using a device where angles are measured in radians. This of course will give approximately $.707$ in both cases as before.

Comment: Why would I get `sin(45) = 0.8509035245341184`? I am executing this in actionscript 3. That is a significant difference and nowhere near `.707`.

Comment: @IAbstract You need to specify degrees, I would guess.

Comment: That is in degrees. You mean radians? Yes, when I converted to radians I received the same result as you: `~ .707`

Comment: @IAbstract I mean your program interprets "sin(45)" as sin(45 radians). You want to type sin(45 degrees) or sin(pi/4).

Comment: This formula doesn't work. I spent half a day debugging, and it's something I can definitely say. E.g. I'm trying to calculate an inertia angle, and when there's none, the car is moving *(along $y$ axis)* $speed * sin(0)$. Now, $sin(0) = 0$, so it's like car is not moving at all — but it clearly should!

Comment: @DavidMitra please could you clarify, in your formula, is the angle $θ$ defined with with relation to the coordinate system beginning, or it doesn't matter? I suspect I might be getting wrong results because I have an angle with relation to the object my car should be driving to.

Comment: FTR, the angle here is relative to origin, which makes sense because given any other random angle, how can you know how does it relate to the coordinate system? In retrospective this wasn't only problem: I'm working with coordinate system with flipped $y$ *(i.e. it grows down, not up)*, which could've caused problem too  *(although it depends on angle definition — if it's also flipped, you don't have to change anything)*. TL;DR: watch out for correct angle offsets, and coordinate system oddness.

Comment: This defines a vector in direction and magnitude, but to actually get the new position, you need to add the origin position.

Answer (score 25):

If you are at point `(x,y)` and you want to move `d` unit in `alpha` angle (in radian), then formula for destination point will be:

```
xx = x + (d * cos(alpha))
yy = y + (d * sin(alpha))
```

**Note**: If angle is given in degree:

```
angle in radian = angle in degree * Pi / 180
```

Comment: can you tell me here d will be in km /m ?

Comment: @Iva the calculation is unit agnostic, d and x/y are in whatever unit you are using