# Calculate point A from given point E and angle and afterwards calculate Point A from E and angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I read some related questions, but I am not sure how to adopt them to my problem. ( Example: [Calculate point, given x, y, angle, and distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143932/calculate-point-given-x-y-angle-and-distance) )

Let's say I have point `E(600|581)` and an angle of `64 degrees`.
To calculate `A` I use the following. `(distance = 133)`

```
radian measure = (2 * PI / 360 ) * (360 - 64)
A.x =  E.x + distance *  cos(radian measure)
A.y =  E.y + distance *  sin(radian measure)

A = (658 | 460)
```

Now how can I get from A back to E? ( Assuming that I dont know the coordinates for A) 
I thougt it would be

```
radian measure = (2 * PI / 360 ) * 64
E.x =  A.x + distance *  cos(radian measure)
E.y =  A.y + distance *  sin(radian measure)
```

But this results in `E = (716|581)`

Changing the `+` to `-` gives the right result.

```
radian measure = (2 * PI / 360 ) * 64
E.x =  A.x - distance *  cos(radian measure)
E.y =  A.y + distance *  sin(radian measure)

E = 600 | 581
```

I just found this by guessing so I am not sure why it is like that and when it has to be like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your numbers are a bit rough. The coordinates of A are $\approx (658.303363, 461.460392)$ to 6 decimal places.

To get back to E from A you need to reverse the angle, i.e add 180° = $\pi$ radians. So since the angle from E to A is -64°, the angle from A to E is 116°.

Now $sin(\pi + \theta) = -sin(\theta)$ and $cos(\pi + \theta) = -cos(\theta)$, so another way to think of this is we keep the original angle and reverse the sign of the distance. So

$e.x = a.x + r \cos(\theta)$
$e.y = a.y + r \sin(\theta)$
where $r = -133$ and $\theta$ = -64°

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing a reflection NOT a rotation. Add $180^o$ instead of subtracting from $360^o$.

Comment: Thank you, I would upvote but I dont have enough reputation.

Comment: @R_Valdez; you do now!