# Calculate 3rd point in a path given angle

Tags: trigonometry

I have 2 points: **p1**, and **p2**. And an angle **deg**:

```
 p2 _ _ _ _p3
 |_|
 | deg
 |
 |
 p1
```

I want to find a third point **p3** (any point on the vector p2->p3) under the condition that it makes the angle **deg** with **p1** & **p2**.

I tried this solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3534251

But it does not work with all angle values..

Comment: There are infinitely many such points, is there some other restriction?

Comment: Say distance 1 from p2.. Thank you!

Comment: The linked question asks about movement in absolute direction, not a relative one, which is what you appear to be asking about, so it’s not surprising that it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you’re working in a right-handed coordinate system and you’re interested in the angle $\theta = \angle{p_1p_2p_3}$ (i.e., that the vertex is at $p_2$ as your ASCII art suggests), use the standard rotation formula to generate a vector that makes the desired angle $\theta$ with $\mathbf v=p_1-p_2$, i.e., $$\mathbf w = (v_x\cos\theta-v_y\sin\theta, v_x\sin\theta+v_y\cos\theta).$$ You can then add any positive multiple of $\mathbf w$ to $p_2$ to get a suitable $p_3$.

Above, I also assumed that the angle is measured counterclockwise from $p_1$ to $p_3$ as per the usual convention. If you’re measuring clockwise instead, replace $\theta$ with $-\theta$ in the above formula.

Comment: Should not `v = p2 - p1` ?

Comment: @light9876 No, because per your illustration the angle is measured at $p_2$, so we want to rotate about that point.

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming the points are coplanar, otherwise there would still be infinitely many points that satisfy the two conditions.

Let the coordinates of $p_3$ be $(a,b)$, and say the known coordinates of $p_2$ are $(x,y)$. We want
$$\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} = 1$$

Let the vector $p_1 \longrightarrow p_2$ be $\vec u$, and the vector $p_2 \longrightarrow p_3$ be $\vec v$ (which you can easily find out). The second condition we have is

$$\cos(\mathbf{deg})=\frac{\vec u \cdot \vec v}{|\vec u|}$$

You can solve the two equations in $a,b$.